# Handling complicated input (with nested values)

Tags: haskell

There is the following task:

1. First line is the number of cases
2. For each case there is a line with the number of numbers to add
3. For each case there is also a line with the numbers
4. For each case I have to print summed numbers

Example:

```
Input:
2
5
1 2 3 4 5
2
-100 100

Output:
15
0
```

This is my implementation

```
import Control.Monad

main = do 
    linesCount <- readLn :: IO Int
    numbers <- replicateM linesCount getCase
    mapM_ putStrLn $ map (show.sum) numbers

getCase :: IO [Int]
getCase = do
    numbersCount <- readLn :: IO Int -- actually I don't need this variable
    numbersString <- getLine
    let numbers = map read $ words numbersString
    return numbers
```

It looks like a lot of code for parsing input. Are there any tricks to "compress" it? :)

Comment: It's 11 lines of not-at-all complicated code. How small do you hope to make it? `mapM_ f $ map g x` can be written `mapM_ (f . g) x`; you could write `getCase` in applicative style, but that saves you maybe 10 characters; you don't need a type signature on the first `readLn`. (Aside: you *do* need `numbersCount` to verify that the user entered well-formed input.)

Comment: Sure, if you want to throw more safety and readability out of the window: ```main = readLn >>= (`replicateM_` (getLine >> (print =<< sum . map read . words <$> getLine)))```. :)

Comment: @Alec This is exactly what I was looking for :). Of course, it's just for academic purposes - for me, to find out some interesting language features.

Comment: @gisek If you go one step further, you can get rid of almost all parens and turn the while thing into an unreadable blob: `main = readLn >>= flip replicateM_ (getLine >> sum . map read . words <$> getLine >>= print)`

Comment: @Alec Very nice :) BTW, if you explained every step of this beast, it would actually be an excellent answer.

Comment: @Alec You can get rid of the last paren using `$`, right? `... flip replicateM_ $ getLine ...`

Comment: @amalloy Nope. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Because then it would be `(readLn >>= flip replicateM_ (...))`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd instead focus on efficiency and good error handling. Handle format errors with `IO` exceptions or `ExceptT`. Can you see why your program could run out of memory if fed a tremendous number of lines? How could you fix that?

Comment: @dfeuer I try to focus on every aspect :). I can see it could run out of memory if a line is very long, although I thought I'm handling only one line at the time. Why would many lines use up all the memory?

Comment: @gisek, `replicateM linesCount getCase` will read in the entire file before allowing you to proceed with printing the output lines. You need to interleave reading and writing. erisco's answer does this by using laziness. Another way is to do it manually in a loop. Another is to use a streaming framework like `pipes`, `conduit`, or `streaming`.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, I didn't expect that

Comment: @Alec I added a secondary answer with the breakdown of your code. Would you mind taking a look if I missed anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you merely want to make code shorter then check out the [Stack Exchange community for code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). That is primarily for fun and games.

If we are thinking there is too much code it may not be that we need to make it shorter but rather that we need to make it *clearer*. Achieving this is a matter of experience and good practice. What we want to do is isolate simple concepts which are obviously correct and then combine them in obviously correct ways. Methodologies include top-down design (break the solution into smaller pieces) and bottom-up design (from smaller pieces build up to the solution) and mixes thereof.

A bottom-up piece that hits me straight away is the task of summing a list of numbers. This has a definition in Haskell's Prelude called `sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`. Somewhere in the final solution we are going to use this.

Another method is to simplify the problem. We can be lead astray by the way a problem is phrased. Upon closer inspection we might find an equivalent and simpler phrasing.

What information do we actually need from the input? Just the lists of numbers. What is the simplest way to obtain the lists of numbers? The number of lists seems irrelevant because there is no need to have this information before we start looking at the lists. Drop the first line and we are left with:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
2
-100 100
```

Then, the length of each list is also irrelevant because we do not need that information before summing the list. Therefore lets also drop every other line from this point:

```
1 2 3 4 5
-100 100
```

Now we just have the lists of numbers separated by line returns where each number is separated by a space.

At this point we have a clear way to break apart the solution in a top-down manner. First we simplify the input. Secondly we parse the lists of numbers. Thirdly we sum the lists. Fourthly we print the sums. This is therefore the skeleton of our solution:

```
simplifyInput :: String -> [String]

parseNumberList :: String -> [Integer]

-- Note we can use `sum` from Prelude to sum the number lists.

printSums :: [Integer] -> IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>= printSums . fmap (sum . parseNumberList) . simplifyInput
```

Now it is just a matter of implementing each obvious piece of the solution.

```
simplifyInput :: String -> [String]
simplifyInput = dropEveryOther . drop 1 . lines
  where
  dropEveryOther :: [a] -> [a]
```

In writing `simplifyInput` I discovered that dropping every other line requires some more work. That is okay, we can just break the solution apart again.

```
dropEveryOther :: [a] -> [a]
dropEveryOther [] = []
dropEveryOther (x:y:xs) = y : dropEveryOther xs
```

Then continuing...

```
parseNumberList :: String -> [Integer]
parseNumberList = fmap read . words

printSums :: [Integer] -> IO ()
printSums = putStr . unlines . fmap show
```

Therefore, in totality:

```
simplifyInput :: String -> [String]
simplifyInput = dropEveryOther . drop 1 . lines
  where
  dropEveryOther :: [a] -> [a]
  dropEveryOther [] = []
  dropEveryOther (_:y:xs) = y : dropEveryOther xs

parseNumberList :: String -> [Integer]
parseNumberList = fmap read . words

printSums :: [Integer] -> IO ()
printSums = putStr . unlines . fmap show

main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>= printSums . fmap (sum . parseNumberList) . simplifyInput
```

The amount of code we have has gone up (compared to the first solution) but in exchange the code is made obvious. Now you should add some documentation comments so we do not forget our explanation for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Alec posted a super compressed version of my original code in one of the comments. I decided to post a small breakdown, in case someone gets lost and has no idea what's going on in there :)

Snippets below need to be preceded with valid imports:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
```

So we start with Alec's version:

```
main = readLn >>= flip replicateM_ (getLine >> sum . map read . words <$> getLine >>= print)
```

He used the `flip` function in order to remove one set of parenthesis:

```
main = readLn >>= (`replicateM_` (getLine >> (print =<< sum . map read . words <$> getLine)))
```

He used the infix notation for `replicateM_` in order to partially apply the second parameter of `replicateM_`, we can replace is with a lambda:

```
main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM_ n (getLine >> (print =<< sum . map read . words <$> getLine))
```

Now let's start extracting some pieces of code into separate meaningful functions:

```
printBatchResult = print =<< sum . map read . words <$> getLine
main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM_ n (getLine >> printBatchResult)
```

We can flip the `print =<<` for more readability:

```
printBatchResult = sum . map read . words <$> getLine >>= print
main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM_ n (getLine >> printBatchResult)
```

And so on:

```
printBatchResult = sum . map read . words <$> getLine >>= print
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult
main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM_ n handleBatch
```

And again:

```
sumLine = sum . map read . words
printBatchResult = sumLine <$> getLine >>= print
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult
main = readLn >>= \n -> replicateM_ n handleBatch
```

And one more time:

```
sumLine = sum . map read . words
handleNumbersLine = sumLine <$> getLine
printBatchResult = handleNumbersLine >>= print
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult
main = readLn >>= (\n -> replicateM_ n handleBatch)
```

And finally the last time:

```
sumLine = sum . map read . words
handleNumbersLine = sumLine <$> getLine
printBatchResult = handleNumbersLine >>= print
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult
handleAllBatches n = replicateM_ n handleBatch
main = readLn >>= handleAllBatches
```

We can replace `<$>` with `fmap`:

```
sumLine = sum . map read . words
handleNumbersLine = fmap sumLine getLine
printBatchResult = handleNumbersLine >>= print
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult
handleAllBatches n = replicateM_ n handleBatch
main = readLn >>= handleAllBatches
```

We can also remove every partial application:

```
sumLine line = (sum . map read . words) line
handleNumbersLine = fmap sumLine getLine
printBatchResult = handleNumbersLine >>= \sum -> print sum
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult
handleAllBatches n = replicateM_ n handleBatch
main = readLn >>= \numberOfBatches -> handleAllBatches numberOfBatches
```

And finally, add signatures:

```
sumLine :: String -> Int
sumLine line = (sum . map read . words) line

handleNumbersLine :: IO Int
handleNumbersLine = fmap sumLine getLine

printBatchResult :: IO ()
printBatchResult = handleNumbersLine >>= \sum -> print sum

handleBatch :: IO ()
handleBatch = getLine >> printBatchResult

handleAllBatches :: Int -> IO ()
handleAllBatches n = replicateM_ n handleBatch

main = readLn >>= \numberOfBatches -> handleAllBatches numberOfBatches
```

Some final comments:

- `>>=` - the `bind` function from monad converts one monad to another (or the same) and transforms its value. In `main` function it takes `IO Int`, transformation lambda and returns `IO ()` - the result of the transformation, which is empty and prints result in the process.
- `>>` - (used in `handleBatch`) ignores the left parameter (how many numbers there are in a line is (arguably) unnecessary) and just returns the right parameter - which is a function handling a line with numbers.

Comment: I'm not really sure if some of the 'functions'  `handleBatch`  e.g. are really functions as they take no parameters. On the other hand, they perform multiple actions with different results, depending on the IO.